# Use JSTL tags in GSP

Tags: grails, groovy, jstl, gsp

I'm trying to use the `c:url` JSTL tag in a GSP. I've added the following declaration to the top of the GSP's layout:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
```

I've also added `jstl-1.1.2.jar` as a depenency. When I call this tag in a GSP:

```
${c.url(value: 'j_spring_security_check')}
```

I get the error:

> Error evaluating expression [c.url(value: 'j_spring_security_check')]
>   on line [27]: Cannot invoke method url() on null object

According to the [Grails docs](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/6.%20The%20Web%20Layer.html#6.3.6%20Using%20JSP%20Tag%20Libraries), the method-style of tag invocation should is supported for JSP tags, so I don't think this is the problem. Do I need to include the JSTL taglib's TLD somewhere in the Grails app in order for this to work?

Comment: Has been answered by http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6900001/where-is-jstl-tld-file

Comment: @BalusC no it hasn't, see my answer below

Comment: It's perhaps just a different (Grails) way to solve the problem :) I don't do Grails, so I can't be sure of this.

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that the problem was this declaration:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
```

For some reason it doesn't work if it's added to the layout, it must appear in the GSP itself. The .tld for the taglib magically appears in `/web-app/WEB-INF/tld` when the dependency on the taglib's JAR is added to `BuildConfig.groovy`