# where is JSTL .tld file?

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

I've downloaded the [jstl-1.1.2.jar](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/jstl/jstl/1.1.2/jstl-1.1.2.jar) from a Maven repository. I expected the .jar to contain the .tld file for the tags, but it doesn't. Does anyone know where I can find it?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

JSTL 1.1 consists usually of two files: `jstl.jar` (the API) and `standard.jar` (the impl). The TLDs are in the `standard.jar`.

In [our JSTL wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info) you can find the right download link for the both JARs.

Answer (score 6):

BalusC was faster with the correct answer, I just want to add that the [standard.jar](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/taglibs/standard/1.1.2/standard-1.1.2.jar) is also available in maven central. Here are the coordinates:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
    <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.2</version>
</dependency>
```